# Unable to redirect to the page based on condition in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing the login form using React.js. Once the user has entered the correct credentials, it should navigate to the dashboard page. Below is my login component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import './login.css';
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
const LoginForm = () => {
    document.body.style = 'background:#20c997';
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    localStorage.setItem("authenticated",false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const permEmail = "piyush@gmail.com";
    const permPass = "pass";

    const handleEmail = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }
    const handlePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("authenticated"));
        if(email===permEmail && password===permPass){
            localStorage.setItem("authenticated",true);
            navigate("/dashboard");
        }else{
            window.alert("Wrong credentials");
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="p-5">
                <div className="container text-start w-25 bg-light text-dark h-50 p-5 border border-primary border-2 rounded">
                    <form>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                className="form-control border border-primary border-1"
                                id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                                placeholder="name@example.com"
                                onChange={(e) => handleEmail(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput2" className="form-label">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className="form-control border border-primary border-1"
                                id="exampleFormControlInput2"
                                placeholder="password"
                                onChange={(e) => handlePassword(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        className="btn btn-outline-primary border-1 mt-2"
                        onClick={e=>handleSubmit(e)}
                        >Submit</button>
                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

In the above code, I'm using localStorage to update the key. Below is the dashboard component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const Dashboard = () => {
    document.body.style = 'background:white';
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(localStorage.getItem("authenticated") || false);
    // useEffect(() => {
    // }, []);
    console.log(authenticated);
    if (!authenticated) {
        return <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
    }
    else {
        return(
            <>
                <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </>
    );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Now, when I open the page using endpoint localhost:3000/dashboard, the value of authenticated in the dashboard component is false, still, it is showing me the Dashboard component, and displaying the "Hello World", in the browser. What I want is when the authenticated is false it should redirect to the login page, which is not happening. I'm not getting why this is happening. Please help me with this.

Comment: Can share a codesandbox or fiddle for your code or may be git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get data from localStorage, it is string. You should convert that to boolean in this case:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const Dashboard = () => {



  let isAuthed = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");

  console.log(typeof(isAuthed)); // returning string

  if (isAuthed == "true") isAuthed = true;// convert to boolean
  else isAuthed = false;    // convert to boolean

  console.log(typeof(isAuthed));  // returning boolean  

  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(isAuthed || false);




  if (!authenticated) {
    return <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default Dashboard;
```

I checked above Code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-kare-hzgw9r?file=/src/Dashboard.jsx

Comment: Hey QasemBSK, your code is working, and I understood now, Thanks for the help.